# Split and return numeric values from a alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "101.75 INR"
```

or

```
var  a = "101 INR"
```

or

```
var a = "101020.3434 INR"

OutPut = 101.75
OutPut = 101
OutPut = 101020.35`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Trim white characters at both ends
2. Define function that decides if a given character is allowed in a number (so all numbers + decimal character + thousand character if there is any)
3. Iterate over each character in string.
4. If character is allowed in number collect it, if not stop iteration.

At the end you will have all the characters of a number. Convert to actual number accordingly to the usual rules.

Alternatively. If you do know that all strings are prices, that is they consist of a number and a currency symbol you may want to just cut out the symbol itself. E.g. replace "ING" with a "", and then convert what's left to a number.

PS If those are a numbers that will be part of further computations you may want to use integers to represent smalles units of given currency to avoid Javascrip floating point issues.